# Output the aria-labelledby parameter for a nav menu child

Tags: menus, walker, twitter-bootstrap

Although i know about [Bootstrap nav menu class](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker), i decided to write my own `Walker`, so i can have better control on what's printed and, in case of need, i have no issues with licenses.

**THE PROBLEM**

My class is, at first look, working in almost all aspects i wanted. Just one issue: for accessibility purposes (and as suggested by Bootstrap's examples), i want to add the `aria-labelledby` attribute to dropdown menus that contain children elements. I'm having hard times with it, because i have not clear what functions are really executed first. My code:

The `start_lvl()` function:

```
public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
        $t = '';
        $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );
        $output .= "{$n}{$indent}<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" aria-labelledby=\"\">{$n}";
    }
```

The `start_el()` function (based on the original from `Walker_Nav_Menu`; check close to the end to see where i modified it)

```
public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
            if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
                $t = '';
                $n = '';
            } else {
                $t = "\t";
                $n = "\n";
            }
            $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( $t, $depth ) : '';

            $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
            $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

            /**
             * Filters the arguments for a single nav menu item.
             *
             * @since 4.4.0
             *
             * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
             * @param WP_Post  $item  Menu item data object.
             * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
             */
            $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

            /**
             * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu item's list item element.
             *
             * @since 3.0.0
             * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
             *
             * @param array    $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
             * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
             * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
             * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
             */
            $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
            $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

            /**
             * Filters the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
             *
             * @since 3.0.1
             * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
             *
             * @param string   $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
             * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
             * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
             * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
             */
            $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
            $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

            $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';

            $atts = array();
            $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
            $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
            $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
            $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

            /**
             * Filters the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
             *
             * @since 3.6.0
             * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
             *
             * @param array $atts {
             *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
             *
             *     @type string $title  Title attribute.
             *     @type string $target Target attribute.
             *     @type string $rel    The rel attribute.
             *     @type string $href   The href attribute.
             * }
             * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
             * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
             * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
             */
            $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

            $attributes = '';
            foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
                if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                    $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                    $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
                }
            }

            /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
            $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

            /**
             * Filters a menu item's title.
             *
             * @since 4.4.0
             *
             * @param string   $title The menu item's title.
             * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
             * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
             * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
             */
            $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );
            if (array_search('menu-item-has-children', $classes, true)) {
                $attributes = ' class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" id = "link-'.$item->ID.'"';
                $title = $title. ' <span class="caret"></span>';
            }
            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            /**
             * Filters a menu item's starting output.
             *
             * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
             * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
             * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
             *
             * @since 3.0.0
             *
             * @param string   $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
             * @param WP_Post  $item        Menu item data object.
             * @param int      $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
             * @param stdClass $args        An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
             */
            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
        }
```

The other functions are untouched. In facts, i need to put something that stays in `start_el()`, but inside `start_lvl()`. As a side note, as far as i know, not even the known nav walker class has this feature. How could i implement it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. I thought it could work but i wasn't sure, and i wanted some opinion from more experienced people. Anyways, this is what i have done:

First of all, i defined a private var in my walker class:

```
private $el;
```

In my `start_el()` function, i filled this var with `$item`

```
$this->el = $item;
```

At this point, i was able to access any item's property from `start_lvl()`

```
$output .= "{$n}{$indent}<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" aria-labelledby=\"link-".$this->el->ID."\">{$n}";
```

Oh well, that was simple, but i hope i'll help someone