# How can i make multilevel menu in wordpress theme with bootstrap

Tags: theme-development, menus

I have used bootstrap nav walker but it works good with just 1 and 2 level  , 3 level is not supported correctly.

I found one here http://www.dangtrinh.com/2015/05/multilevel-drop-down-menu-in-wordpress.html

but it is not that good .

How can I make navigation like one in blazok theme on themeforest.

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried and what you mean by "it is not that good"? With walkers I suggest you start out coding your HTML exactly as you want it to appear when rendered and troubleshoot any CSS and JS in that hard-coded copy. Next, you use a walker to slowly tweak WP's output until it matches your hard-coded HTML. It can be a process but you need to complete at least part of that process yourself. It's a good learning experience. :)

Comment: Basically what I'm saying is - please provide a little code, and break your task into smaller steps. Folks here are better able to help with each small step where you get stuck. Most questions that ask for a full-blown solution go unanswered.

Comment: I used navwlker class .....and it didn't work for 3 depth menu....then i tried this modification in code. http://www.dangtrinh.com/2015/05/multilevel-drop-down-menu-in-wordpress.html   but this one is so vague means not user friendly at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download  [Bootstrap nav walker file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1mlr5jLh4p8TEFya1JsQmQzWW8).Call this file to your functions.php. Then Put this code to dynamic your nav menu:

```
 <?php
                        $args = array(
                            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                            'menu'              => 'Main',
                            'container'         => 'false',
                            'container_class'   => '',
                            'container_id'      => '',
                            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
                            'menu_id'           => '',
                            'echo'              => true,
                            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_page_menu',
                            'before'            => '',
                            'after'             => '',
                            'link_before'       => '',
                            'link_after'        => '',
                            'items_wrap'        => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                            'depth'             => 5,
                            'walker'            => new my_custom_walker_nav_menu()
                        );

                        wp_nav_menu ($args);
                        ?>
```

You can choose the value to the 'depth' key how many depth you need

Comment: drive file link is not working

Answer (score 0):

I myself have wrote [a class](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/268571/output-the-aria-labelledby-parameter-for-a-nav-menu-child/) that can achieve this result. In any case, you need to write a `Walker` class (more precisely your class should extend `Walker_Nav_Menu`) and override the methods you need to change. Finally, include it in functions.php, inside a check for existing `Walker_Nav_Menu`. In code:

```
if (class_exists('Walker_Nav_Menu')) {
    class Walker_Custom_Bootstrap_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
        //Override Walker Methods
    }
}
```

Check more at [the code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/), or study the file `/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php` which is very well commented.

I hope i'll be helpful for you.